# university word

Tags: verbs, vocabulary

In my country if university students get a GPA under 12 they become conditional.

I was wondering if the verb ((become)) is correct for this state.

shall we say:

I became conditional this semester?

or there is another verb for it?

Comment: If you're going to use ***conditional*** then *became* seems ok.  You might also consider "I was ***reclassified*** [as] conditional"

Comment: Like most technical terms regarding schools, it matters a great deal **where** the school is located, and what languages are spoken there, besides (one assumes) English. You can't ask worldwide opinion about how to use local dialects locally; talk to the locals and listen to how they talk about it. If you are a local, then you already know.

Comment: ***You*** become conditional (as opposed to being a fact)? I find that expression extremely strange. I would assume your *attendance* would become conditional—or perhaps that you became a *conditional* ***student***. But for *you* to become conditional doesn't sound right to me at all.

Comment: By the way, what is the maximum GPA in your country?  In the USA it's typically 4.

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard the word **conditional** used like this. Things like offers can be conditional, but people can not be.

In the United States, the phrase **academic probation** is used for the consequences of a low GPA. For example, Columbia University has the following [policy](http://bulletin.columbia.edu/columbia-college/regulations/):

> Students may be **placed on academic probation** for the following reasons: [other reasons] ... or earning a term or cumulative grade point average below 2.0...

You may be referring to a **conditional offer of admission** which is an offer of admission, usually to a school, conditioned on performance. For example, you could be offered admission to a university conditioned on attaining a certain GPA when you graduate high school.

Comment: I take it you speak AmE (like me). Is that right? 'conditional' is surely BrE or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Became is fine for conditional.

I was placed/put on conditional or academic probation.

Less formally, "I got conditional/probation this semester."